# Error al ejecutar servidor Tomcat Apache en Eclipse en proyecto específico. Funcionando de la misma manera en otro proyecto

Tags: java, apache, java-ee, tomcat

Cada vez que intento ejecutar un proyecto de Java EE en eclipse salta este error en consola:

```
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Nombre de la versión del servidor:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.54

may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Apr 3 2020 14:06:10 UTC
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Número de versión de servidor:         8.5.54.0
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 10
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Versión de Systema Operativo:      10.0

may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Arquitectura:          amd64

may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_241-b07
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Vededor JVM:     Oracle Corporation
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\saura\Proyectos Programación\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.54
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\saura\Proyectos Programación\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.54
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\saura\Proyectos Programación\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.54\endorsed
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\saura\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\saura\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\SauraSMaker\Descargas;;.]
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Inicializando el manejador de protocolo ["http-nio-8080"]

may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 925 ms
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
may 05, 2020 1:44:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54
may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Los servlets llamados [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVote] y [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVoteAndComment] estan ambos mapeados al patrón de URL [/AddVote] el cual no esta permitido
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2408)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2084)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1965)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Los servlets llamados [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVote] y [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVoteAndComment] estan ambos mapeados al patrón de URL [/AddVote] el cual no esta permitido
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2408)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2084)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1965)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Tomcat no puede iniciar porque el componente Server requerido fallo al iniciar.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Practica_DAD_2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Los servlets llamados [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVote] y [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVoteAndComment] estan ambos mapeados al patrón de URL [/AddVote] el cual no esta permitido
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2408)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2084)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1965)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Parando servicio [Catalina]
may 05, 2020 1:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

He intentado de todo para poder solucionarlo:

- Desinstalar eclipse y reinstalarlo.
- Eliminar el servidor Tomcat Apache 8.5 y volver a descargarlo.
- Crear nuevo servidor en eclipse enlazando el nuevo Tomcat Apache descargado.
- Creando un nuevo proyecto desde cero copiando los archivos relevantes como son los de Java Resources y los de dentro de WebContent generando, eso si, un nuevo web.xml.

Además, busqué en más foros de stack overflow, tanto en inglés como español, pero no encontré una solución propuesta que me ayudara, puesto que las apliqué todas y no funcionó. A lo mejor es que no supe aplicarlo, por lo que pido paciencia y en cuyo caso una explicación a fondo de como poder solucionar este error.

Cabe destacar que fue de un día para otro. Antes funcionaba perfectamente con todos y cada uno de los proyectos que tengo.

Por último, he de decir que he creado un nuevo proyecto súper simple con un index.jsp con un form y un servlet /Login y funciona perfectamente utilizando el mismo Tomcat Apache creando un servidor distinto en eclipse. Sin embargo, al crear nuevo proyecto y copiar los archivos del que no funcionaba, sigue sin funcionar. Ni siquiera funciona en caso de que copie los mencionados archivos en el proyecto de prueba que antes SI funcionaba.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el contenido de tu web.xml? Fíjate en este error: Los servlets llamados [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVote] y [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVoteAndComment] estan ambos mapeados al patrón de URL [/AddVote] el cual no esta permitido

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ese era el problema. No sé cómo no pude darme cuenta. Disculpad las molestias.

Comment: Te animo si tienes un momento a escribir una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, indicando como lo has resuelto, para que así poder ayudar a otras personas que tengan un error parecido al tuyo.

Answer (score 2):

Citando a [ordago - QUÉDATE EN CASA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/142239/ordago-qu%C3%89date-en-casa)

> Fíjate en este error: Los servlets llamados [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVote] y [edu.ucam.servlets.AddVoteAndComment] estan ambos mapeados al patrón de URL [/AddVote] el cual no esta permitido

El problema es que dos servlets del mismo proyecto eran mapeados con el mismo patrón de URL, simplemente cambiando la URL de mapeado a una única se soluciona el error.

Servlet AddVoteAndComment:

```
@WebServlet("/AddVote")
public class AddVoteAndComment extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddVoteAndComment() {
        super();
    }
```

Servlet AddVote:

```
@WebServlet("/AddVote")
public class AddVote extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AddVote() {
    super();
}
```

Como podéis ver en @WebServlet("") las dos clases tienen el mismo texto entrecomillado, eso es lo que se debe cambiar para solucionar el error.